# Rename files in a bulk from csv file in Powerhshell

Tags: powershell, csv

**Renaming files from a CSV**

I am trying to write a script to reorganize files in a folder structure using csv as index file but I can´t figure out in how to solve the Rename-Item error.

Questions

1. Is there others way to write this script in order to achieve the same results more easily?
2. How to pass the right parameters to Rename-Item?

**My csv file template**

```
folderName                          newName                                      oldName          
----------                          -------                                      -------          
01 Course Overview                  01_Course_Overview                           1280x720.mp4     
02 Introduction to PowerShell       01_Introduction to PowerShell                1280x720 (1).mp4 
02 Introduction to PowerShell       02_Who Is This Course For?                   1280x720 (2).mp4 
02 Introduction to PowerShell       03_What Is PowerShell?                       1280x720 (3).mp4 
02 Introduction to PowerShell       04_Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7       1280x720 (4).mp4
```

**PowerShell Script**

```
$csv = Import-Csv '.\index.csv' -Delimiter ';'
$newFolders = $csv.folderName | Sort-Object -Unique
$listFolders = Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object Name
$listFiles = Get-ChildItem | Where {$_.extension -eq ".mp4"}

ForEach ($a in $newFolders){
    
    If ($listFolders.Name -contains $a){
        Write-Host "The Folder $a exist"
    }
    else{
        New-Item -Path $pwd.Path -Name $a -Type Directory | Out-Null
        Write-Host "The folder $a has been created"
    }

}

ForEach ($b in $csv){
    
    If ($listFiles.Name -contains $b.oldName){
        Write-Host "File $($b.oldName) exist"
        Write-Host "Renaming file to: "$($b.newName)"
        
        #Rename-Item $($b.oldName) -NewName $($b.newName)
        #Write-Host "Moving file to: "$($b.folderName)"
        #Move-Item .\$($b.newName) -Destination .\$($b.folderName)
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "File $($b.oldName) doesn't exist" `n
    }
    
}
```

**Error when executin Rename-Item**

```
No D:\Downloads\Pluralsight\_PowerShell_Essentials\01_Powershell_Getting_Started\Temp\indexfiles.ps1:30 caractere:9
+         Rename-Item $($b.oldName) -NewName $($b.newName)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (D:\Downloads\Pl...280x720 (2).mp4:String) [Rename-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your csv?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I added csv file template in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example of how this can be done, this is mainly a test case, it will create the files as you show us on the CSV and move them to the new folders based on the `folderName` column.

The code will look for the files on the current directory, before testing it with the real files, `Set-Location` (`cd`) to that folder.

If you're not sure if the code will work you can add a `-WhatIf` switch to `Rename-Item` and `Move-Item`.

**Note**, I have removed `?` from the `newName` column since it's an invalid character on Windows. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names) for more details.

```
# Go to a temporary folder for testing
Set-Location path/to/temporaryfolder/here

# Here you would use:
# $csv = Import-Csv path/to/csv.csv
$csv = @'
folderName                          newName                                      oldName
01 Course Overview                  01_Course_Overview                           1280x720.mp4
02 Introduction to PowerShell       01_Introduction to PowerShell                1280x720 (1).mp4
02 Introduction to PowerShell       02_Who Is This Course For                    1280x720 (2).mp4
02 Introduction to PowerShell       03_What Is PowerShell                        1280x720 (3).mp4
02 Introduction to PowerShell       04_Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7       1280x720 (4).mp4
'@ -replace '  +',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Create test files, this part is only for testing the code
$csv.foreach({ New-Item $_.oldName -ItemType File })

foreach($line in $csv)
{
    if(-not (Test-Path $line.folderName))
    {
        # Create the Folder if it does not exist
        New-Item $line.folderName -ItemType Directory -Verbose
    }
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $line.oldName -NewName $line.newName
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $line.newName -Destination $line.folderName
}
```

Comment: @chrispaiva I'm guessing this could be because your files could have invalid characters in their name. See my update, using `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`. Hope it works

Comment: Really nice and easier approach Santiago, but I am still getting some erros and I guess it is because filename has special caracters in the name.

MODO DETALHADO: Realizando a operação "Renomear Arquivo" no destino "Item: D:\Downloads\Pluralsight\_PowerShell_Essentials\01_Powershell_Getting_Started\Teste\1280x720 (3).mp4 Destino: **D:\Downloads\Pluralsight\_PowerShell_Essentials\01_Powershell_Getting_Started\Teste\03_What Is PowerShell?".**

Comment: @chrispaiva see my comment above and the update using `-LiteralPath`. It should work with it

Comment: Even with -Literalpah I got errors, but is because special caracters like **?** I need to correct it inside csv or replace it in powershell and then update csv to have the names without those caracters. Thanks for your prompt response and help.

Comment: @chrispaiva yes `?` is an invalid character and I would definitely not recommend to use it on files or folders. See this answer for the list of invalid chars: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/15339544. I'm quite sure that if you remove them from your CSV the script should work fine, as long as the original files don't have special characters too

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your real CSV file contains folder and/or file names with characters that are invalid like the `?`.

To fix that, you can choose to remove those characters from the CSV file first, OR make sure you remove them before creating a folder or renaming a file.
For both options, you can use this small helper function:

```
function Remove-InvalidNameChars {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String]$Name,

        [ValidateSet('File', 'Path')]
        [string]$Type ='File'
    )

    if ($Type -eq 'File') {
        $invalidChars = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''
    }
    else {
        $invalidChars = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidPathChars() -join ''
    } 
    # build a regex string from the invalid characters
    $removeThese = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape($invalidChars)
    # output the name with invalid characters removed
    $Name -replace $removeThese
}
```

**Method 1:** remove the invalid characters from the CSV file and use cleaned-up data:

```
$sourcePath = 'D:\Test'
$csvFile    = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath 'index.csv'
$csvData    = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile -Delimiter ';'
foreach ($item in $csvData) {
    $item.folderName = Remove-InvalidNameChars -Name $item.folderName -Type Path
    $item.newName    = Remove-InvalidNameChars -Name $item.newName -Type File
}
$csvData | Export-Csv -Path $csvFile -Delimiter ';' -Force  # rewrite the CSV file if you like

# now use the cleaned-up data in $csvData for the rest of the code:
foreach ($item in $csvData) {
    # create the output folder if this does not already exist
    $targetPath = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath $item.folderName
    $null = New-Item -Path $targetPath -ItemType Directory -Force
    # move and rename the file if found
    $sourceFile = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath $item.oldName
    if (Test-Path -Path $sourceFile -PathType Leaf) {
        $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $targetPath -ChildPath $item.newName
        Move-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $targetFile
    }
}
```

**Method 2:** leave the csv data as-is and make sure you remove invalid characters while renaming/moving:

```
$sourcePath = 'D:\Test'
$csvFile    = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath 'index.csv'
$csvData    = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile -Delimiter ';'
foreach ($item in $csvData) {
    # create the output folder if this does not already exist
    $targetPath = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath (Remove-InvalidNameChars -Name $item.folderName -Type Path)
    $null = New-Item -Path $targetPath -ItemType Directory -Force
    # move and rename the file if found
    $sourceFile = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath (Remove-InvalidNameChars -Name $item.oldName -Type File)
    if (Test-Path -Path $sourceFile -PathType Leaf) {
        $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $targetPath -ChildPath (Remove-InvalidNameChars -Name $item.newName -Type File)
        Move-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $targetFile
    }
}
```

<sup>Note that `Move-Item` can move a file to a new destination and rename it at the same time, so you do not need `Rename-Item`</sup>

---

P.S. I noticed in your example CSV there are no extensions to the `newName` filenames..
If that is the case in real life, you need to add these aswell.

For that change the `Move-Item` line to:

```
Move-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination ([IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($targetFile, [IO.Path]::GetExtension($sourceFile)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Theo.
Regex is another science under study aroud here. :-)